# Issue with relationships in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to know if my model relationships are correct. I am creating a discovery platform, to allow users to search various product items. Thank you for the help!

I have four `models`: Product, Boutique, ProductCategory & Designer

`Every Product, has a Designer.`

`Every Product, has a ProductCategory.`

`Every Boutique, has a Product and the Product is related to a Designer`

`Every Designer, has a Product and the Product is related to a Boutique.`

My `model.py` Code Below:

**Designer**

```
class Designer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    label_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    specialites = models.CharField(max_length=254,  null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/designers/main',max_length=100, null=True) #For the argument upload_to, will add to the static folder and generated image will be stored in suing that path specified

    #For Admin Purposes, to track and see which if still active by for administrative users only
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #Foreign Keys & other relationships
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    boutiques = models.ManyToManyField(Boutique)

    #Metadata
    class Meta:
         verbose_name = _("Designer Information")

    #Helps return something meaningful, to show within the admin interface for easy interaction
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

**Product**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)    
    color_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    size_types = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True, blank=True)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2, blank=True,default=0.00) #To show original price if, new price has been added
    product_tags = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for product tag area')
    novelty = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    product_website = models.URLField(max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True) #To show other sites to Users, where they can purchase the particular product
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/products/main',max_length=100, null=True) #For the argument upload_to, will add to the static folder and generated image will be stored in suing that path specified
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name.')

    #This shows when each item was uploaded & by who, to the User 
    uploaded_by = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    #For Admin Purposes, to track and see which if still active by for administrative users only
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #Foreign Keys & other relationships
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory)
    boutiques = models.ManyToManyField(Boutique)
    designer = models.ForeignKey(Designer)

    #Metadata
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Product")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Products")

    #Helps return something meaningful, to show within the admin interface for easy interaction
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**ProductCategory**

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True, null=True)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name.')

   #For Admin Purposes, to track and see which if still active by for administrative users only
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   #For Admin Purposes, to track when we add each product and each product was updated by administrative users
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   #Helps return something meaningful, to show within the admin interface for easy interaction
   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name
```

**Boutique**

```
class Boutique(models.Model):
        boutique_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)    
        city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
        zipcode = models.IntergerField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
        boutique_website = models.URLField(max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True)

        #For Admin Purposes, to track a product to see which is active by administrative users
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

        #Foreign Keys & other relationships
        product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
        designer = models.ManyToManyField(Designer)

       #Metadata
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = _("Boutique Information")

       #Helps return something meaningful, to show within the admin interface for easy interaction
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt your `models` are *correct*.

I think this is what you're trying to do:

1. There's a `Designer`.
2. A `Designer` can have many `Boutiques`.
3. A `Boutique` can have many `Products` in it.
4. A `Product` is also related to a `ProductCategory`.

So the relationship should be like `Designer > Boutique > Product` *i.e.* A `Designer` creates a `Boutique` and adds some `Products` in it after associating it with a `ProductCategory`.

That means:

1. The `Designer` should not have any `ForeignKey` fields, rather ***it*** should be a `ForeignKey` to the `Boutique` and `Product` models.
2. The model `Boutique` should have a `ForeignKey` relating to `Designer`, **not** to `Product`.
3. The model `ProductCategory` shouldn't have a `ForeignKey` field. But ***it*** should be a `ForeignKey` to `Product`.
4. The model `Product` should have **three** `ForeignKey`s relating to `Designer`, `Boutique` and `ProductCategory`.

So, by all this, your models should look somewhat like below:

```
class Designer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Other fields here ...
    # Don't create any ForeignKey fields


class Boutique(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(Designer)
    # Other fields here ...
    # No need for any more ForeignKeys


class ProductCategory(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Other fields ...
    # This model doesn't need any ForeignKey field


class Product(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(Designer)
    boutique = models.ForeignKey(Boutique)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Other fields here ...
```

It's all similar to the *Poll* tutorial in Django docs. There, you create a *poll* which has many *choices*. So, the `Choice` model has a `ForeignKey` to `Poll` model, not *vice versa*.